# Como deshabilitar modulos

Tags: apache

¿Cómo hago para desactivar lo que hace ***mod_evasive***?
¿Basta con solo comentar el contenido del archivo?

Por las dudas aclaro que estoy trabajando con Python y Django.

Gracias!!

Comment: Probé sólo la opción que me dio **JackNavaRow**
La otra no la llevé a cabo, por lo que quizás también funciona...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Recuerda que Evasive (minimizar ataques HTTP DoS)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_denegaci%C3%B3n_de_servicio)

Para desactivar un modulo en Apache2 existe el comando [a2dismod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/a2enmod.8.html)

```
sudo a2dismod  evasive
```

Para activarlo :

```
 sudo a2enmod evasive
```

> Puedes ver la carpeta `/etc/apache2/` existe carpetas como mod-enable
>   mod-available, lo que hace el comando es crear un enlace simbolicode
>   una carpeta a otra (en windows se llama acceso directo) funciona igual
>   para los virtualhost y los comandos `a2insite` y `a2disite`

Una vez ejecutados algunos de estos comandos no olvide reiniciar Apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Parece que me funcionó :-)

Answer (score 2):

Si trabajas con eso, puedes desinstalar  el evasive.

Ejecute el siguiente comando.

```
sudo apt-get uninstall libapache2-mod-evasive
```

reinicia apache

```
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
```