# Prevenir ataques HTTP a servidor apache

Tags: apache

Como podría prevenir o mitigar un ataque de solicitudes `HTTP` masivos, la pregunta surge porque hace unos días se cayeron los servicios de un servidor con `apache` que tengo a mi cargo.

Investigando en los `logs`, vi el log de acceso de apache y me percate que justo antes de la hora de la caída de los servicios, una dirección IP realizo mas de `19,000 solicitudes HTTP` en menos de 10 minutos a rutas no existentes de mi servidor.

Comment: Este es un tema bastante amplio, te recomiendo leer https://www.esecurityplanet.com/network-security/how-to-prevent-ddos-attacks.html, para hacerte una idea. Un saludo.

Comment: [Instala la libreria evasive](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/273806/28035)

Answer (score 3):

Podés usar Mod_Security y Mod_Evasive:

Mod_Security hace las veces de firewall para nuestras web-apps, además de monitorizar el tráfico en tiempo real, ayudándonos a defendernos contra ataques por fuerza bruta.

Instalar este módulo no es más complejo que ejecutar los siguientes comandos:

En Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-modsecurity
sudo a2enmod mod-security
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

En CentOS, RHEL, Fedora:

```
sudo yum install mod_security
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Mod_evasive previene ataques DDoS y ataques por fuerza bruta, procesando cada petición con detenimiento analizando su composición. Usa tres métodos de detección:

- Si detecta muchas peticiones a una misma página un unos pocos segundos.
- Si cualquier proceso trata de realizar más de cincuenta peticiones concurrentes.
- Si una IP sigue intentando hacer nuevas peticiones cuando ésta se encuentra en lista negra.

Para su instalación sólo deberemos ejecutar estos comandos.

Para CentOS, Fedora, RHEL:

```
sudo yum install mod_evasive
```

Para Ubuntu, Debian

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-evasive
```

te dejo el link con la info en español:

https://openwebinars.net/blog/seguridad-en-apache-modsecurity/

Answer (score 2):

puedes bloquear las conexiones via iptables.
Ej para evitar ataques de fuerza bruta a ssh se hace:

```
## anti DOS SSH (maximo 5 conexiones a los 300 segundos)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH -m comment --comment 'ssh max 5/5min'
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 5 --name SSH -j DROP
```

Esto es super-bestia. limita a 5 conexiones cada 5 minutos.

---

Para http podrias limitar a 50 conexiones por segundo.

```
## anti DOS http (maximo 50 conexiones por segundo)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name http -m comment --comment 'http max 50/s'
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 50 --name http -j DROP
```

Según esto si una ip solicita mas de 50 conexiones por segundo.
El kernel de linux solo aceptara las 50 primeras conexiones por segundo. el resto serán desechadas(DROP) (Ni siquiera llegaran al apache)

Primero puedes probar ejecutando estas lineas a mano. (con un reinicio el servidor quedaría como antes).

y si quieres que sea definitivo. añade estas lineas a /etc/rc.local o a la configuración de  iptables.

Comment: Muchas gracias! se ve bastante eficiente esto.

Comment: Gracias a ti también se agradecen las buenas valoraciones. Tengo 7 servidores. y llevo mas de un año trabajando en "hardening". las técnicas hardening consisten en endurecer a los servidores frente ataques. lo digo por si quieres buscar mas información para contener y detectar ataques.